# Open File based on Dictionary Value matched to Public Variable

Tags: vba, dictionary

I have an excel file with a list of codes in column 1 relating to different workbooks.

At first I created a code that would loop through the codes and I would manually open the specific workbook using "Application.GetOpenFilename".

Now, I decided to make it more efficient and because the file path doesn't change I figured I'd create a global public variable with the file path location.

I create a dictionary that adds all the codes. (That is the loop between 2 and 50) The value in each row of Cells(i,1) contains an abbreviated code which is then tied to a public variable with the full file path/location.  In this case, all the codes in rows 2 through 50 are ABC123 (key = ABC123).  Other times I have multiple codes, which is why I add to a dictionary to keep the unique values and can then open these individual files.

I was hoping to loop through the dictionary to open the specific files related to the code, instead it tried to open the string value rather than the file path. ABC123.xls rather than C:\Users\xxxx\xxxx\ImportantFile2018.xls

I'm trying to figure how to get the dictionary key to equal the public variable I assigned with the same name.

Do not get hung up on variable names, these are just examples. The major issue is how to retrieve the variables value (file path) when the variable name (ABC123) matches a cell's value.  Every cell value in column 1of the data has a matching variable with a filepath.

```
Option Explicit
Public ABC123 As String

Sub DefinedVariables()

ABC123 = C:\Users\xxxx\xxxx\ImportantFile2018.xls

End Sub

Sub Reporting_Update()
Dim dictClient As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim key As Variant

Call DefinedVariables

For i = 2 To 50
    If dictClient.Exists(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
    Else:
        dictClient.Add Cells(i, 1).Value
    End If
Next

For Each key In dictClient
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=key
```

Comment: In the immediate window I type ?key and it says ABC123, I hover over that it and shows me the C:\Users\xxxx\xxxx\ImportantFile2018.xls  I just can't get it to open that file path as it still looks for ABC123.xls.  I also tried adding another variable as a string, then Workbooks.Open FileName:= Evaluate(clientLocation) and get a type mismatch error

Comment: #1) Don't get too hung up on Cells(i,1).  The value in i,1 = ABC123 for this example.  So now I need to open the file path associated with the ABC123 variable from my public variable. #2) It doesn't contain the file name. #3) ABC123 is just an example of an abbreviated file name which again has a file path/location assigned to it.  #4) Again, don't get too caught up on the cells(i,1); what I am trying to do is open a file location based on the coding in a specific cell.  If cell(2,1) was XYZ456 then I would want it to pull the file path from my public variable assigned to XYZ456.

Comment: I have yet to find any information on how to access a variable's value if a cell value has the same name as the variable.  (IE Above, Cells 2,1 = ABC123, and if ABC123 is the variable, I can't get the actual value to ABC123 by referencing Cells 2,1.  Unfortunately, I may have to create an array with all my different abbreviated codes and their file paths to access the information.

Comment: For starters string literals should be declared between "". Also, your base path is a constant and can be declared at procedure level unless you are using it elsewhere.

Comment: Don't call a variable ABC123 it is not descriptive (slightly irrelevant but it is also a valid cell reference.). You have put a full filepath into the variable. Don't you just want the path upto the containing folder then you concantenate in your filenames (with extension) from the dictionary? Hard to tell without any real data and expected output shown. You can also use overwrite syntax to add to a dictionary   dictClient(Cells(i, 1).Value) = Cells(i, 1).Value. Fully qualify your range objects with the parent worksheet and don't rely on bug prone activesheet references.

Comment: Be wary of any character limitiations on what you can put in a dictionary - be sure to check you dictionary contains the expected values. And you don't need to use _Call_

Comment: And please [edit] all info into your question not as comments as I indeed risked getting too hung up on _ABC123_ .

Comment: I appreciate the feedback but the above is just example data to hopefully minimize confusion but all responses so far (not sure why the other individual deleted his comment) don't seem to be focusing on the real issue of how to retrieve a variable's value (file path) if the variable (ABC123) matches a cell value. (Cell2,1)=ABC123.

Comment: Oh.... I get it (I think).... you are trying to access a variable using a literal string. You can't. ABC123 != "ABC123".  Put the filenames in the sheet and put the path upto the containing folder into the variable (make it a constant as I mention above). Then concantenate the file name (with extension) on to the constant to get the full file path.

Comment: I think that's what i realized after googling the past 5 hours haha.  I think ill create a master data table, run that through a dictionary and keep the row number as the item so i can retrieve info like worksheet.open cells(dict(key), folderpathColumn).value.  can't just concatenate cause even though the value ABC123 is the cell value, the actual file doesn't say ABC123. I think i have a work around. Thanks for your help